# Use assets in folder only when on page X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've got a folder of js files that I want to include only when I'm on my dashboard page(or controller).

Can I exclude that folder from my application.js's `//= require_tree .` file and only include it in my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have application.js require only some files, rather than the everything-and-the-kitchen-sink approach of `require_tree .`

For instance, make a directory structure like this:

```
javascripts/
  application.js
  special.js
  common/
    foo.js
    bar.js
  special/
    other.js
```

Then have application.js only include files in the "common" directory by using

```
= require_tree ./common
```

Meanwhile, "special.js" (find a better name, obviously), require everything in "special"

```
= require_tree ./special
```

Then you'll have to tell Rails that "special.js" should be pre-compiled by the asset pipeline (if you do use asset precompilation). This is done in `config/production.rb`, and there's already a commented line there showing to to do it. So just uncomment and edit that line, and you should get:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( special.js )
```

If you don't do this, the precompilation will only look at application.js (the default)

Finally, in the relevant views, you can include the special JS by saying

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "special" %>
```

You can just place that at the bottom of the file

Answer (score 0):

You can create another js file - dashboard.js, and include it only for dashboard controller

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => 'dashboard') %>    
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'dashboard' %>
<% else %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<% end %>
```

In your environments/production.rb just add

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(dashboard.js)
```